# jQuery wont work? animate function

Tags: jquery, function, jquery-animate

**Hello stackoverflow**

Im running through some tutorials to jQuery, cause i wanna start a 2d chat.

I have a code that should make some images at 50% opacity, and 100% when a mouser hover the images, but it wont work? The images is 50%, but wont change to 100%.

**My code:**

```
$(function(){

    $('#container img').animate({
        "opacity" : .50
    });

    $('#container img').hover(function() {
        $(this).animate({  "opactiy": 1  });
        console.log("Den er nu 100% klar");
    });

});
```

Comment: Come on .... **opactiy**

Comment: Also you need a second hover function to again reduce the opacity, if that's the effect you're aiming for...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just change `opactiy` to `opacity` in your second `.animate()`:

```
$(function(){

    $('#container img').animate({
        "opacity" : .50
    });

    $('#container img').hover(function() {
        $(this).animate({  "opacity": 1  }); // <-- Right here
        console.log("Den er nu 100% klar");
    });

});​
```

[**jsFiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/x7f2W/)

Answer (score 1):

You've got a typo in your hover statement:

```
 $(this).animate({  "opactiy": 1  });
```

should be:

```
 $(this).animate({  "opacity": 1  });
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$(function(){

    $('#container img').animate({
        opacity : '1'
    });

    $('#container img').hover(function() {
        $(this).animate({  opacity:'0.5'  });

    },function(){
            $(this).animate({ opacity:'1'  });

    });

});​
```

[JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/AeCWv/)